# WAMP Dependencies for Installation

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp, wampserver, windows-server-2012-r2

I was able to successfully install WAMP on my local machine and get WordPress working locally. I am trying to install WAMP on Windows Server 2012 R2 and keep receiving dll errors. I've done some research and have installed Visual C++ Redistributable per some users' suggestion on the server prior to installing WAMP. This is the error I keep receiving.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you installed the VC Runtime **after** installing WAMP, uninstall WAMP and reinstall.

Comment: If in doubt you can always look at the WAMPServer forum [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)